# Distance calculation with callback inside .NET gridwiew

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, callback

I have built a grid of coordinates to calculate the distances and apply some logic, row by row.
I have to calculate the distance between point A and point B, or if I have a point C, the distance between point A and point B and between point B and point C, and add the two values.

I tried to use a callback function, but the return value received in the calculation of the distance between point B and point C is always the last pair of coordinates and not that of the current line.
What is the error in the attached function? And how can I make my call less "cumbersome".

Thank you

```
function GetDistance(img, txtRimborso, hfImportoRimborso, hfLastOfTheDay) {
    var latA = img.attributes['latA'].value;
    var lngA = img.attributes['lngA'].value;
    var latB = img.attributes['latB'].value;
    var lngB = img.attributes['lngB'].value;
    var latC = img.attributes['latC'].value;
    var lngC = img.attributes['lngC'].value;

    var isLastOfTheDay = hfLastOfTheDay.value;
    var distance;

    source = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);
    destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB);

    GetDist(source, destination, function () {
        distanceA = Number(this);

        if (latC == '' && lngC == '') 
        {
            console.log('latC = \'\' lngC = \'\'');
            source = new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB);
            destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);

            GetDist(source, destination, function () {
                distanceB = Number(this);

                var fullDistance = Number(((Math.floor(distanceA / 1000))) + Number((Math.floor(distanceB / 1000))));
                console.log('A: ' + Math.floor(distanceA / 1000) + ' B: ' + Math.floor(distanceB / 1000) + ' = ' + fullDistance);

            });

        } else if (isLastOfTheDay == 'True') {
            console.log('isLastOfTheDay: ' + isLastOfTheDay);
            source = new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB);
            destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latC, lngC);

            GetDist(source, destination, function () {
                distanceB = Number(this);

                var fullDistance = Number(((Math.floor(distanceA / 1000))) + Number((Math.floor(distanceB / 1000))));
                console.log('A: ' + Math.floor(distanceA / 1000) + ' B: ' + Math.floor(distanceB / 1000) + ' = ' + fullDistance);

            });

        } else {
            var fullDistance = (Math.floor(distanceA / 1000));

        }

    });
}

function GetDist(source, destination, fn) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [source],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: true,
        avoidTolls: true
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            fn.call(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
        }
        else
            fn.call(0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, using waypoint

```
function GetDistance(img, lRimborsoKm, txtRimborso, hfImportoRimborso, hfLastOfTheDay) {

        var latA = img.attributes['latA'].value;
        var lngA = img.attributes['lngA'].value;
        var latB = img.attributes['latB'].value;
        var lngB = img.attributes['lngB'].value;
        var latC = img.attributes['latC'].value;
        var lngC = img.attributes['lngC'].value;

        var isLastOfTheDay = hfLastOfTheDay.value;


        if (latC == '' && lngC == '')  // A -> B + B -> A
        {
            source = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);
            destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);
            var waypts = [];
            waypts.push({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB),
                stopover: true
            })
            GetDist(source, destination, waypts, function () {
                distance = Number(this);

                var fullDistance = Number(distance);
            });

        } else if (isLastOfTheDay == 'True') {  // A -> B + B -> C

            source = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);
            destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latC, lngC);
            var waypts = [];
            waypts.push({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB),
                stopover: true
            })
            GetDist(source, destination, waypts, function () {
                distance = Number(this);

                var fullDistance = Number(distance);
            });

        } else {    // A -> B
            source = new google.maps.LatLng(latA, lngA);
            destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latB, lngB);
            var waypts = [];

            GetDist(source, destination, waypts, function () {
                distance = Number(this);

                var fullDistance = Number(distance);
            });
        }
    }

    function GetDist(source, destination, waypts, fn) {

        directionsService.route({
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            avoidHighways: true,
            avoidTolls: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                var route = response.routes[0];
                var distance = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                    var routeSegment = i + 1;
                    distance += Math.floor(route.legs[i].distance.value / 1000);
                }
                fn.call(distance);
            } else {
                fn.call(0);
                console.log(status);
                console.log('latA: ' + source.lat() + ', lngA: ' + source.lng() + ', latB: ' + destination.lat() + ',lngB: ' + destination.lng());
            }
        });
    }
```